# How to flat a subarray in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

`select array[[1,2],[2,3]]`

Output:
`-[ RECORD 1 ]-------- array | {{1,2},{2,3}}`

How do I flat the array, so I can then unnest?

Expected `{1, 2, 2, 3}`

Comment: Why don't you simply use `select array[1,2,3,4]`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i can't change dataset, this is just a simplication

Comment: Then please show us the real data and what you really want to do (probably doing an UPDATE to change existing rows). Simplifying your question is a good thing, but simplifying it to a point where you won't get a helpful answer not so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unnest()` completely flattens the array.  If you need the flattened array, then `unnest()` and follow with an `array_agg()`

```
select array_agg(el order by rn)
  from unnest(array[array[1,2],array[2,3]]) 
         with ordinality as a(el, rn);

 array_agg 
-----------
 {1,2,2,3}
(1 row)
```